# Get json data from wiktionary

Tags: javascript

Im trying to develop an app like wordle with javascript and wiktionary api.

So, when i try to send fetch request using this code:

```
const url = `https://en.m.wiktionary.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=apple&format=json`;

fetch(url)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
    console.log(data);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error("Error:", error);
  });
```

I receive "failed to fetch" error.

I also tryed to make this using XMLHttpRequest with

```
const url = `https://en.wiktionary.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=apple&format=json`;

const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.open("GET", url, true);

xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && xhr.status === 200) {
    const response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
    console.log(response);
  } else if (xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
    console.error("error:", xhr.status);
  }
};

xhr.send();
```

This code also returns a 0 error.
So, how to parse this json data from wiktionary without jquery?

Comment: Please read [ask]; provide a [mcve]; quote the **full** set of error messages.

Comment: The Wiktionary URL does not want to be called [cross-origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/CORS).

Comment: Uh, why are you using two different URLs?

Comment: So, what i should to do?

Comment: @Bergi they are the same and contains same json data

Comment: @JamesF One begins with `https://en.m.wiktionary.org`, the other with `https://en.wiktionary.org`. They might return the same response but they also might not

Comment: @Bergi i tryed each link with all my attemptions, but result is same - error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've debugged the issue with the browser console and found the following error message.

"From origin 'https://example.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled."

Since, it's a CORS policy issue, you may need to try running your code from a local server or using a browser extension that allows you to bypass CORS restrictions during development.

However, you can try the following alternative methods to fetch data:

**JSONP fetch method**

```js
const url = 'https://en.m.wiktionary.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=apple&format=json&callback=processData';

function processData(data) {
  console.log(data);
}

const script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = url;
document.head.appendChild(script);
```

**Adding `origin=*` parameter to the fetch URL**

As said in the previous answer, it also works.

```js
const url = `https://en.m.wiktionary.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=apple&format=json&origin=*`;

fetch(url)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
    console.log(data);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error("Error:", error);
  });
```

If you're running this code from a web page hosted on a different domain other than "en.m.wiktionary.org," the browser may block the request due to CORS restrictions. Try any of the above methods, definitely one of them will work for you.

Answer (score 1):

So, if it wiil help anyone in future
As @HeikoTheißen said, CORS block access and i fixed that with adding `origin=*` to the link!